Error in the Picker component when binding the ItemsSource property
I have the following code:
XAML:
<StackLayout>
    <Picker Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"  MinimumWidthRequest="120"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit}"    
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding UnitName}">
    </Picker>
    <Button Text="Change"
        Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>

Cs:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Unit> units;
    public ObservableCollection<Unit> Units
    {
        get { return units; }
        set
        {
            units = value;
            //SelectedUnit = null;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            SelectedUnit = Units.First();
        }
    }

    private Unit selectedUnit;
    public Unit SelectedUnit
    {
        get { return selectedUnit; }
        set
        {
            selectedUnit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        Units = new ObservableCollection<Unit>()
        {
            new Unit("Meter (m)"),
            new Unit("Decimeter (dm)"),
            new Unit("Centimeter (cm)"),
            new Unit("Milimeter (mm)"),
            new Unit("Foot (ft)"),
            new Unit("Inch (in)")
        };

        SelectedUnit = Units.First();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Units = new ObservableCollection<Unit>()
    {
        new Unit("Kilogram (kg)"),
        new Unit("Pound (lbs)"),
        new Unit("Ounce (oz)"),
    };
    }
}

public class Unit
{
    public Unit(string unitName)
    {
        UnitName = unitName;
    }

    public string UnitName { get; }
}

I run the program and select any of the last three items in the Picker component. Then I click the button to change the displayed collection in the Picker component.
.Net7.0:
The Picker displays the new collection, and the first item is selected.
.Net8.0:
After clicking the button, I encounter an error in the Units property, specifically when calling the OnPropertyChanged method:
Value does not fall within the expected range.
To make the program work, I need to uncomment the line that is located before this method.
I know that the problem is going out of the collection range using the SelectedIndex property. However, in .NET 7, that value is set to -1.
Is the behavior in .NET 8 incorrect, or was it intentional?

What happens when you swap the call order of those lines: OnPropertyChanged();  SelectedUnit = Units.First(); ?

When I swap these instructions, I don't get an error, but the value in the SelectedUnit property will be null.

what is the value of value when the exception occurs?

this collection Units = new ObservableCollection()
{
new Unit("Kilogram (kg)"),
new Unit("Pound (lbs)"),
new Unit("Ounce (oz)"),
};

I test your code, but it works fine.

Which .net version did you test in?

My version is .net 8.0 .

You select "Milimeter (mm)" or "Foot (ft)" or "Inch (in)" and then press button?
